# What is wrong in this sorting?

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

In a recent interview I was asked to write sorting algorithm. I did it in following way. I wanted to understand what is wrong in this approach? When I test with 500 intergers it gives better time complexity than bubble sort. Reason I am asking is, that interviewer failed me for this.

```
static int[] SortedNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
        {
            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
            numbers[i + 1] = temp;
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[i])
                {
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about Big-Oh analysis.  Pick up an algorithms book.

Comment: I do agree with all other answers and comments, but I do have to point out the line `if (i > 0)` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively a bubble sort. The interviewer might have wanted to hear about some well known, more efficient algorithms like [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort%20Quicksort). If you are going to an interview, be prepeared with well known algorithms, do no invent your own!

Also when you argue about run time of an algorithm, do not use a specific set of data on which the algorithm operates, but rather talk about run time characteristic. This may be a good entry point to research the subject:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation